# How Android adb can see my files when the storage is encrypted

Tags: android, encryption, adb

When I connect my Android device to a computer, ADB on Android can always see my device files even when everything is encrypted. Does anybody have an explanation? I mean how the terminal can decrypt my files without entering any password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enabled USB debugging on that device in the developer menu and authorized it for debugging, you implicitly gave up your encryption secrets to the connected computer.  Disable adb debugging or revoke USB debugging authorizations in the developer settings menu, and access to files via adb shell should disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That explains how adb can access the files. However, when I change the password on my device, the secrets should change as well right?. So the device should reauthorize the pc to access the files but that doesn't happen... The terminal still able to access the data without any new authorization. Do you know what is really happening behind the scenes?

Comment: I don't know for a fact, but I would guess that the password is just used to gain entry at the time of device boot, while the adb "backdoor" isn't subject to needing any password since the adb process on the device run just like any other process that can run at any time after the device boots.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about full-disk encryption before Android M(5.0), the sample answer is once you enter the Android, the /data portion is decrypted.

Reason: when **full-disk encrypted(FDE)**, the portion just simply can't mount. So, disk must be decrypted when boots up. This feature only ensure your data security when  device is power-off.

In Android N(6.0), **file-based encryption(FBE)** is enabled to ensure your data security in running time.

For more detail, please check: https://source.android.com/security/encryption/